# Terraform external data source formatting issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want a list of my s3 buckets in TF.

With the AWS CLI I can get that list and format it into JSON:

```
my-mac$ eval aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}' | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")' | jq '.[:-1]'

[

  "xxx-bucket-1",

  "xxx-bucket-2"

]
```

But TF won't fetch it, and it's driving me mad.

Here's my data source config:

```
data "external" "bucket_objects" {

  program = ["bash", "cli.sh"]

}
```

The shell script file contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

eval aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}' | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")' | jq '.[:-1]'
```

And finally, the error message:

```
│ Error: Unexpected External Program Results

│ 

│   with data.external.bucket_objects,

│   on data.tf line 22, in data "external" "bucket_objects":

│   22:   program = ["bash", "cli.sh"]

│ 

│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.

│ 

│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.

│ 

│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's

│ logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:

│ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging

│ 

│ Program: /bin/bash

│ Result Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type

│ map[string]string
```

My shell scripting game is weak and it's going to be something dumb, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: This is just a list right? So I don't think that's a properly formatted json. You probably need a key as well, something like `"bucket_names": ["xxx-bucket-1", "xxx-bucket-2"]`. The example from the docs says to use `jq` to have a properly formatted JSON: `jq -n --arg foobaz "$FOOBAZ" '{"foobaz":$foobaz}'`.

Comment: @MarkoE `["xxx-bucket-1", "xxx-bucket-2"]` outside of an object is still valid JSON.

Comment: @jordanm Ok, I did not know that. :) Care to share some reading material?

Comment: @MarkoE Don't know about reading material but you can test this in your browser console with `JSON.parse("[1,2,3,4]")` or CLI with `printf '[1,2,3,4]' | jq`. All valid json data types can be the entire json document. Even `"foo"` is valid json.

Comment: Hm, that actually makes sense, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that worked in my case:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

BUCKET_NAMES=$(aws s3 ls | awk '{print $3}' | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")' | jq '.[:-1]')

jq -n --arg bucket_names "$BUCKET_NAMES" '{"bucket_names":$bucket_names}'
```